# How to show constant value in rdoc?

Tags: ruby, rdoc

Is it possible to have rdoc also show value of constant, not just it's comment? At the moment it's generating

```
Constants

DEFAULT_CONFIG_FILE

    Default configuration file location
```

what I would like to get is

```
Constants

DEFAULT_CONFIG_FILE = '~/config.yaml'

    Default configuration file location
```

given source code

```
DEFAULT_CONFIG_FILE = '~/config.yaml'
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [create a custom template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15764193/4931).

[Here is the offending line in the template](https://github.com/ruby/rdoc/blob/master/lib/rdoc/generator/template/darkfish/class.rhtml#L54) that only shows the name. You'll have to add a reference to [`const.value`](https://github.com/ruby/rdoc/blob/master/lib/rdoc/constant.rb#L22).

Maybe something as simple as:

```
<dt id="<%= const.name %>"><%= const.name %> = <%= const.value %>
```